# How does 'Trust this computer' work in Google's 2 step authentication?

Tags: two-factor-authentication, google-authenticator

I have seen this option 'Trust this computer' feature in Google and some other famous sites. How does this work?

What information about my computer is being stored in their server? Or is it based on cookie -- in that case, if I delete cookies will it stop working?

Please share if you have any information about its inner working. Thanks.

Comment: As the first result I get by googling for `google "trust this computer"` contains the answer for how they do it (in Google's support site), I'd say your question lacks research effort...

Comment: My bad. Cookies it is!

Comment: Actually, I think they're doing something extra. When I go to Google Accounts to see the devices I've said they can trust, they list my machine name ie "Andrew's iPhone". How do they get *that*? I didn't know you could via Javascript or anything else for that matter!

Answer (score 1):

Cookies yeah! If you delete them, you gotta login again!